# Angular api rest, la peticion ajax no me devuelve lo que deberia

Tags: ajax, angular, api

Estoy haciendo un login y me encuentro con el problema de que no me recupera bien el valor de mi api rest.
Estoy llamando a una `URI` que unas que se le pasara  o bien  **email y password** o **usuario y password**.
La api funciona bien, lo he probado en **postman** y todo sin problemas, pero al llevarlo a angular ya empiezan los problemas.

Primero valido el **frontend**
 y una vez que esta todo correcto valido el **backend**

A continuacion dejo mis funciones :

```
  validarFormularioFrontend() {
    let valido = true;


    if (!this.usuario.usuario.trim().length) {
      this.addError("El usuario/email no puede estar vacio");
      valido = false;
    }
    if (!this.usuario.password) {
      this.addError("La contraseña no puede estar vacia");
      valido = false;
    }




    return valido;

  }
  //VALIDACION BACKEND

  existeEmailPassword() {
    let usuario: Usuario = null;

    this.usuarioService.loginE(this.usuario.usuario, this.usuario.password)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          if (result) {
            usuario = result;

          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log("ERROR LOGIN E = " + error);

        }
      )



    return usuario;
  }

  existeUsuarioPassword() {
    let usuario :Usuario = null;


    this.usuarioService.loginU(this.usuario.usuario, this.usuario.password)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          if (result) {
            usuario = result;
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log("ERROR LOGIN U = " + error);
        }
      )


    return usuario;
  }

  validarFormularioBackend() {

    let usuario: Usuario = null;

    console.log("exist E = " + this.existeEmailPassword());
    console.log("exist U = " + this.existeUsuarioPassword());


    if (this.existeEmailPassword()) {
      usuario = this.existeEmailPassword();
    }

    if (this.existeUsuarioPassword()) {
      usuario = this.existeEmailPassword();
    }


    return usuario;


  }

  iniciarSesion() {
    this.vaciarErrores();

    if (this.validarFormularioFrontend()) {
      if (this.validarFormularioBackend()) {
        alert("SESION INICIADA CON EXITO");
        let usuario:Usuario = this.validarFormularioBackend();
        //console.log("EL USUARIO QUE HA INICIADO SESION ES = ",usuario);
      }
    }
  }
```

Como se puede apreciar `iniciarSesion()` se encarga de todo. El problema esta en que me devuelve null siempre las funciones `existeEmailPassword()` y `existeUsuarioPassword()`. Una de las dos me debe dvolver **null** si , pero no las dos, ya que a veces el usuario iniciara con el **email** y otras con el **nombre de usuario**.

Las direcciones de las API son:

**Para comprobar si es con el email:** 
 `http://localhost:8090/api/usuarios/existE/{email}/{password}`

**Para comprobar si es con el usuario:** 
 `http://localhost:8090/api/usuarios/existU/{usuario}/{password}`

Por **arrojar mas luz** cuando hago un console log del usuario (una vez igualado al resultado de la peticion ajax) me sale el objeto recuperado perfectamente. Por tante en algun momento la var usuario vale el valor que deberia pero alguna razon se borra luego.

Tambien aclarar que si os fijais, si intenta conectarse ya sea por email o por nombre de usuario yo le paso siempre `usuario.usuario` y no : `usuario.email` o `usuario.usuario` eso se debe a que esta mapeado a un objeto **Usuario** y por tanto lo mapee con el atributo usuario:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="usuario.usuario" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en la forma en que devuelves el usuario en existeEmailPassword() y existeUsuarioPassword().

El **return usuario** está fuera del **subscribe** y siempre va a ser undefined, ya que javascript es asíncrono y no espera a this.usuarioService.loginE, sino que sigue ejecutando y hace el return antes de que el servidor te devuelva la respuesta.

Toda la lógica la debes tener dentro del subscribe().

Además, deberías pasar el e-mail y usuario al servidor y que sea éste el que se fije si existe el e-mail o usuario, haciendo de este modo solo una llamada http al servidor y mejorando la performance.

Una forma de arreglarlo puede ser transformando los subscribe en map y hacer el subscribe en iniciarSesion:

```
private existeUsuario() {
  return this.usuarioService.login(this.usuario.usuario, this.usuario.password).pipe(
    map(
      result => {
        return result;
      },
      error => {
        console.log('ERROR LOGIN E = ' + error);
      }
    )
  );
}

private validarFormularioBackend() {
  return this.existeUsuario();
}

public iniciarSesion() {
  this.vaciarErrores();

  if (this.validarFormularioFrontend()) {
    this.validarFormularioBackend().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        alert("SESION INICIADA CON EXITO");
        let usuario: Usuario = result;
        console.log("EL USUARIO QUE HA INICIADO SESION ES = ",usuario);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Para hacer una sola llamada, tendrías que pasarle el e-mail, nombre de usuario y password al backend, y que sea éste el que tenga la lógica de busqueda de usuario.

El código Java en el backend podría ser algo así:

```
public login(String email, String nombreUsuario, String password){

  String usuario;
  usuario = buscarPorMail(email);
  if (usuario = null) {
    usuario = buscarPorUsuario(nombreUsuario);
  }
  return usuario;
}

private String buscarPorMail(String mail){
  // acá tienes que buscar el usuario
  if () {
    return "usuario";
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

private String buscarPorUsuario(String nombreUsuario){
  // acá tienes que buscar el usuario
  if () {
    return "usuario";
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Hay que trabajarlo un poco más, pero la idea es que sea el backend el que busque por e-mail o nombre de usuario, y te devuelva si encontró o no el usuario, y si además el password es correcto.

Comment: HOla, gracias por contestar. Veo que me dices que seria mejor hacerlo desde el backend. A ver mi backend esta hecho en spring, y esta hecho de forma api rest. No se como podria verificarlo desde el backend, pero me interesa, ya que si mejora el rendimiento es algo que busco. Esas validaciones como se podria hacer desde el backend?

Comment: Añadido el código en Java, es un ejemplo, tendrías que adaptarlo a tu API.

Comment: Pero como lo tengo yo no es el backend quien lo busca ? Realmente la logica fuerte esta en el backend no ¿

Comment: Si, en este caso la lógica fuerte te conviene ponerla en el backend. El cambio que te propongo es que en lugar de tener 2 funciones: existeEmailPassword y existeUsuarioPassword (que a su vez tienen 2 funciones en el servicio: usuarioService.loginU y usuarioService.loginE),  pases a tener 1 sola función existeUsuario (con 1 función en el servicio). Y que le pases al backend en la misma llamada el mail, usuario y password

Comment: Bueno pero independientemete de hacerlo mas optimo o no, el problema sigue . El tema es que al hacer asincrono no lo hace en el momento que debe y se demora el resultado y es por eso que nunca llegan a concordarse. El tema principal de la cuestion es que como puedo atrapar el resulta de la peticion http sin que se escape ?

Comment: El resultado dentro de **this.validarFormularioBackend().subscribe** está bien?